# Why can't I find my application on the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

We recently released an application update on the Google Play Store.

Now some tablets that previously could download it can no longer.

As you can see in the gradle the minimum version is Android 8.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 26 //Android 8
    targetSdkVersion 29 //Android 10
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 106
    versionName "7.2"
}
```

Here is what we are asking for in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"   />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"   />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC_TRANSACTION_EVENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"   android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Our customers' table is Samsung Galaxy Tab (10.1 "2019) but by analyzing the list of devices that we support and do not support in the catalog of devices on Google Play Console, we have noticed that many tablets are excluded.

Our customers' table is Samsung Galaxy Tab (10.1 "2019) but by analyzing the list of devices that we support and do not support in the catalog of devices on Google Play Console, we have noticed that many tablets are excluded.

Unfortunately our tablet is not present in the catalog so we cannot get more information.

Tablet information:

- Android 9
- DISPLAY 10,1" 1200 X 1920 PX
- FOTOCAMERA 8 MPX Ƒ/2.0
- CPU OCTA 1.8 GHZ
- RAM 3 GB

Comment: Did you add any of the "android:required" manifest fields with this update?

Comment: Yes, we brought "android.hardware.camera" to android:required="true"  but the tablet has a camera. Can this be our problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the following line of code:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Even if the device in question has the camera module (actually who from Android 8 onwards does not have a camera module?) The Google Play Store does not think so.
As advised by [Shawn Hazen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016852/shawn-hazen)  the problem was resolved by bringing the value to false.